# API worked on postman and some real devices but not all in react native app

Tags: asp.net, react-native, asp.net-mvc-4

I am integrating API with react native. API's are developed in Asp.net framework. I am very surprised that API works in some devices fine and not in all devices. I dont understand why it happens.
It happens in the following scenario.

- Emulator works fine.
- Intex (Android 5.1) works fine.
- Mi phone (Android 8.1) not working.
- Samsung Tab (Android 5.1.1) works fine.
- Samsung phone not working.

I don't understand is it react native problem or server(API) problem. here are my code and I am using react-naive 0.57 version.

```
  getData() {
    fetch('http://192.168.2.42:83/WebServices/GetData.asmx/CheckMembershipLogin?UserName=demo@gmail&Password=M$d3')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
        // alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("error" + error);
      });
  }
```

Error

[image]

API also work on POSTMAN. but when I test it https://apitester.com/ It through me this error.

```
 Trying 103.255.106.140...
Name '0.0.0.0' family 2 resolved to '0.0.0.0' family 2
Local port: 0
connect to 103.255.106.140 port 80 failed: No route to host
Failed to connect to redmilgroup.aspwork.co.in port 80: No route to host
Closing connection 0
```

API developed in **ASP.net framework 4.5 with TLS FILE 1.2**

Comment: there are many similar questions with same issue(git also as i know), probably not api's probeblem but rn itself.

Comment: check if the device and API are on same network

Comment: Is your API exposed on a public IP address (103.255.106.14)? Your JS snippet shows you're consuming the API over LAN.

Answer (score -1):

Please Check your Network connection.

Comment: Your Mobile data or WIFI Should be On

Comment: I test with both mobile and wifi data. It is not an Internet connection issue.